# how to sort class on datetime, sort collections.deque

Tags: python, unit-testing, sorting, python-2.7, comparison

I could really use some help in how to implement the **getitem**, **iter** methods or generator functions to sort a class and class container I have created.

I created a Report class that has send_time (datetime) and period_length (int) attribues.
I also created a ReportDeque container for Reports, which inherits from collections.deque.

I need to add sorting functionality to both the class and it's container.

So far, I have sorted working ok, but would like to get list.sort() style working.

```
  sortedList = sorted(list, key=lambda report: report.send_time)
  sortedDeque = sorted(deque, key=lambda report: report.send_time)
```

I am struggling to implement the **getitem** in Report, and the **iter**, next methods in ReportDeque. I just can't seem to find the examples I need to get all this working.

Maybe generator functions should be used to sort collections.deque container.
It would be nice to have a variety of generators to sort deque in different ways.

Below is my test case. To run the unittest in code below type:

```
  python -m unittest test_reports
```

Output is at end of this post.

Thanks in advance...

------------------- test_reports.py snip --------------------------

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from datetime import datetime
from collections import deque
import unittest
import inspect

class Report(object):
    """
    Contains all information contained in a report
    """
    def __init__(self, periodStart, periodEnd, sendTime):
        self.period_start = periodStart
        self.period_end = periodEnd
        self.send_time = sendTime
        self.send_timestamp = (sendTime - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
        self.period_length = (periodEnd - periodStart).total_seconds()

    #def __getitem__(self, key):

class ReportDeque(deque):
    """
    Container for processing, sorting Report objects
    """

    #def __iter__(self)

    #def next(self)

class TestReports(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):

        self.list = []
        self.deque = ReportDeque()

        # send_time 12/4/13, day length report
        report = Report(datetime(2013, 12, 3, 0), datetime(2013, 12, 3, 23), datetime(2013, 12, 4, 0))
        self.list.append(report)
        self.deque.append(report)
        # send_time 12/3/13, day length report
        report = Report(datetime(2013, 12, 2, 0), datetime(2013, 12, 2, 23), datetime(2013, 12, 3, 0))
        self.list.append(report)
        self.deque.append(report)
        # send_time 12/2/13, day length report
        report = Report(datetime(2013, 12, 1, 0), datetime(2013, 12, 1, 23), datetime(2013, 12, 2, 0))
        self.list.append(report)
        self.deque.append(report)

        # sorted with key function works
        self.sortedList = sorted(self.list, key=lambda report: report.send_time)
        self.sortedDeque = sorted(self.deque, key=lambda report: report.send_time)

    def test_sort_deque_send_time(self):
        self.print_inspect()
        # deque does not have sort method. How to sort it?
        self.deque.sort()
        firstReport = self.deque[0]
        print "send_time {} period_length {}".format(firstReport.send_time, firstReport.period_length)
        self.assertEqual(firstReport.send_time, datetime(2013, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0))

    def test_sort_list_send_time(self):
        self.print_inspect()
        # list.sort() not working. How to implement __get_item___?
        self.list.sort()
        firstReport = self.list[0]
        print "send_time {} period_length {}".format(firstReport.send_time, firstReport.period_length)
        self.assertEqual(firstReport.send_time, datetime(2013, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0))

    def test_sorted_deque_send_time(self):
        self.print_inspect()
        firstReport = self.sortedDeque[0]
        print "send_time {} period_length {}".format(firstReport.send_time, firstReport.period_length)
        self.assertEqual(firstReport.send_time, datetime(2013, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0))

    def test_sorted_list_send_time(self):
        self.print_inspect()
        firstReport = self.sortedList[0]
        print "send_time {} period_length {}".format(firstReport.send_time, firstReport.period_length)
        self.assertEqual(firstReport.send_time, datetime(2013, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0))

    def print_inspect(self):
        calling_function = inspect.stack()[1][3]
        print "\nin {}()".format(calling_function)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

------------------- test_reports.py snip --------------------------

```
    $ python -m unittest test_reports


    in test_sort_deque_send_time()
    E
    in test_sort_list_send_time()
    send_time 2013-12-04 00:00:00 period_length 82800.0
    F
    in test_sorted_deque_send_time()
    send_time 2013-12-02 00:00:00 period_length 82800.0
    .
    in test_sorted_list_send_time()
    send_time 2013-12-02 00:00:00 period_length 82800.0
    .
    ======================================================================
    ERROR: test_sort_deque_send_time (test_reports.TestReports)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test_reports.py", line 51, in test_sort_deque_send_time
        self.deque.sort()
    AttributeError: 'ReportsDeque' object has no attribute 'sort'

    ======================================================================
    FAIL: test_sort_list_send_time (test_reports.TestReports)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "test_reports.py", line 62, in test_sort_list_send_time
        self.assertEqual(firstReport.send_time, datetime(2013, 12, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0))
    AssertionError: datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 4, 0, 0) != datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 2, 0, 0)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.011s

FAILED (failures=1, errors=1)
```

Comment: Is it `ReportsDeque` or `ReportDeque`?

Comment: I originally named the collection of reports ReportsDeque (plural) but kept typing in ReportDeque (singular) over and over by mistake, so I renamed it ReportDeque (singlular) in code example. Are there syntax errors? The plural might be a better name really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you need to make your Report objects comparable, so you can order without an explicit key. You should probably read up on rich comparisons, but `__cmp__` will do the trick.

```
class Report(object):
    """
    Contains all information contained in a report
    """
    def __init__(self, periodStart, periodEnd, sendTime):
        self.period_start = periodStart
        self.period_end = periodEnd
        self.send_time = sendTime
        self.send_timestamp = (sendTime - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
        self.period_length = (periodEnd - periodStart).total_seconds()

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.send_time, other.send_time)
```

That's all you need to get your tests to pass when you're testing `list.sort()`. The tests for `sorted(list)` and `sorted(deque)` should work too, but there's a catch. Since you're asking for help with a `__getitem__` implementation, I think you believe `sorted()` is doing the sort in-place, and will sort your deque in-place too. That's not how it works. `sorted(iterable)` will return a new sorted list with the items of your iterable.

If you really want to sort your deque in place, you'll have to implement a deque sorting algorithm in the `deque.sort()` method to do it in place, and I have no idea which algorithm would be more efficient for sorting a deque (I'm not even sure if it makes sense to do that), but I think it's probably easier for you to rebuild the deque and leverage on python's very efficient sorting algorithm:

```
class ReportDeque(deque):
    """
    Container for processing, sorting Report objects
    """

    def sort(self, *args, **kwargs):        
        items = [self.pop() for x in xrange(len(self))]
        items.sort(*args, **kwargs)
        self.extend(items)
```

And that should get all your tests passing.

**Update**

If you want `period_length` to be used for disambiguation when send_time is equal, you just add that to `__cmp__`, like this:

```
    def __cmp__(self, other):
         cmp((self.send_time, self.period_length), 
             (other.send_time, other.period_length))
```

Comment: Obligatory code golf: `def sort(self, *args, **kwargs): self.extend(sorted(self.pop() for x in xrange(len(self)), *args, **kwargs))`

Comment: Definitely. That was my first implementation. :)

Comment: Thank you Pedro & Kindal. Just back from lunch, and will get to work on it. Defining __cmp__ makes sense. I was staring at __getitem__ and __iter__ thinking 'what the heck!' I am aware that sorted() returns list, and it's nice this code works `sortedDeque = sorted(deque, key=lambda report: report.send_time)` Might be an efficient sort for deque. Answers to deque.sort() algorithm are much appreciated because I ultimately want to implement ReportDeque sort() and sort on first send_time (oldest to newest) and then (when send_time equal) period_length (smallest to largest).

Comment: @BradSturtevant with `__cmp__`, sorted(deque) works too, without the key parameter. The secondary sorting condition you mention is also part of `__cmp__`, it has nothing to do with deque.sort(). I'll edit the answer to add that. I really doubt any deque sort() algorithm one can implement will be better than python's builtin list.sort(), even at the cost of rebuildiing the deque.

Comment: @Pedro Thanks again, 'checked' your answer